# "außer" as conjunction - is it "restriktiv"?

Tags: conjunction

On their site about the *Modalsatz*, canoo.net  consideres both, "außer" and "insofern" as conjunctions that introduce a [*Restriktivsatz*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Adverbial/Modal.html#Anchor-Der-14210), while I think they are completely different.

I can understand "insofern" restricts the meaning of the first sentence, but "außer" is not restricting . As I understand, it rather means: if the second sentence is correct, then first sentence will not be correct, for example:

> Sie können das Spiel nicht mehr gewinnen, außer wenn sie ein Wunder schaffen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the site you linked the following definition of "Restriktivsatz" is given:

> Ein Restriktivsatz schränkt den Geltungsbereich des im Hauptsatz genannten Geschehens ein.

This means that a "Restriktivsatz" is defining conditions under which the rest of the sentence is true.

Using the word "*außer*" you define such a condition:

A sentence is true **under the condition** that some **other condition** is **not** true.